# How to create inner join with multiple conditions in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, inner-join

I want to achieve the following query with hibernate:

```
SELECT * form A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id AND B.someOtherColumn = 5
```

I don't know how to add the AND statement.

Comment: if you are using Hibernate so for above code you can use Criteria

Comment: Can you add an example?

Answer (score 4):

#### A) Criteria

If there is any association between A and B classes like B is inside A then you can use the query below:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
criteria.setFetchMode("a.b", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("a.b", "b");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("b.someOtherColumn", 5));

List list=criteria.list();
```

#### B) HQL

Also you can use below HQL query try this if B is inside A.

```
select a from A a where a.b.someOtherColumn = 5
```

#### C) @Where annotation

If you want make the collection implicitly filtered, you can use `@Where` annotation on the collection mapping.

```
@Where(clause="someOtherColumn = 5")
```

#### D) @Filter annotation

Works similarly to `@Where` but you can use variable in clause. You need to explicitly enable and set the variables value per session.

#### E) createAlias() with `withClause` parameter

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
criteria.createAlias("a.b", "b", JoinType.INNER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("b.someOtherColumn", 5));

List list=criteria.list();
```

Comment: Creating an alias using the withClause (E) causes the association not to be eagerly fetched. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using where instead..

```
SELECT * from A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id WHERE B.someOtherColumn = 5
```

Comment: But I'm afraid it's not the same. In the first statement it'll join only on rows where someOtherColumn = 5 while in the second statement it'll join on all rows and only then do the where part?

Comment: Of course. I'm talking about the process. Isn't the second one is less efficient?

Comment: @John Ephraim, is there any association between A and B classes?

Comment: @julius_am, the performance should be the same - it depends on the query planner of your database to optimize the join given the restrictions in `WHERE` clause. If in doubt see `EXPLAIN` of the query.